# Salesforce - Azure Integration

Tags: azure

Is anyone can help me with the integration of Salesforce with Azure,

Achived: 1) Get all the records from the Storage container from the azure into salesforce
2) Able to post the data from salesforce to Azure

Question: Not able to retrieve the data based on the record Id, from Azure into Salesforce, can anyone help on this.

**WEb Service:** https://assetdev.blob.core.windows.net/opencontainer/?comp=list
**Service Type : Get**
**Response :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EnumerationResults ContainerName="https://assetdev.blob.core.windows.net/opencontainer/">
    <Blobs>
        <Blob>
            <Name>0x8D9776CC0662C88.jpg</Name>
            <Url>https://assetdev.blob.core.windows.net/opencontainer/0x8D9776CC0662C88.jpg</Url>
            <LastModified>Sat, 25 Sep 2021 13:50:23 GMT</LastModified>
            <Etag>0x8D9802B6BFF2034</Etag>
            <Size>170108</Size>
            <ContentType>application/json</ContentType>
            <ContentEncoding />
            <ContentLanguage />
        </Blob>
```

**Tried with web service:** https://assetdev.blob.core.windows.net/opencontainer/0x8D97F6B52C756FD?api-version=2020-04-08

**Bypassing the Etag_id, but getting the error message:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
        <Message>The specified blob does not exist.
    RequestId:38a69c40-801e-0057-5faa-badb74000000
    Time:2021-10-06T12:03:25.6712454Z</Message>
    </Error>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo - your blob name ends in `.jpg` and you didn't include that in your GET.

Comment: Also: Please be mindful of tags: your question is only about Azure storage (blobs). I removed all unrelated tags, accordingly.

Comment: Looks like a typo - your blob name ends in .jpg, Yes because I am posting an image into that blob and with refering its documents and posting the REST call from postman it take as it is. If you are more aware then let me know how can I make it done

Comment: Also: Please be mindful of tags: your question is only about Azure storage (blobs). I removed all unrelated tags, accordingly. – 
David Makogon
 What do you mean, My question is to how can I fetch the Specific record from the Azure Blob list based on the Id, for that I have added the required information that I had tried what is worng in it?

Comment: I don't really understand your comments, but... what I'm telling you is, your blob listing shows a blob name ending in `.jpg` and your follow-on call omits the `.jpg`. I went and made a GET to your endpoint and retrieved the blob with no problem, using the full name.

Comment: As for tags: you tagged this as `[azure-devops]` but it has nothing to do with Azure DevOps. Same with the `[salesforce]` tags - this is only about Azure blobs as written. I'm just saying, please don't add tags that aren't directly related to a question.

Comment: Also, to be clear about blobs: there are no "records" in blobs - every blob is its own thing, with its own unique name. And its "id" is its full path+name.